# What is stopping us from splitting an electron?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, standard-model, elementary-particles

If we could split an electron, we would probably find new things. So, why don't we shoot a lot of energy at it, and see what happens? I tried looking up what happens, but I got no good answers.

Comment: Well, because GeV class electron beams have been around for some time now, with lots of scattering experiments showing that we can't split it (so far at least).

Comment: Why the downvotes? I feel like this was downvoted only because it's a short question or something, or maybe because there are no equations. It seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't show enough previous effort.

Comment: @doublefelix "Why the downvotes?" If you hover your mouse over the down arrow, you will see a set of suggested down-vote reasons. I think a better question is: why the upvotes?

Comment: Some comments suggest that this question is trivial or obvious. Since no one actually knows the answer, as I have elaborated below, I disagree.

Comment: @rob Which comments? Some of the answers seems to suggest it is trivial or "by definition." But I'm not seeing any comments that suggest triviality or obviousness. The substantial comments I see suggest that OP didn't put any effort into answering OP's own question.

Answer (score 9):

We don't know why we can't split an electron.

Contrary to another answer, we don't know whether the electron is a fundamental particle or a composite of some number of other things.  Since we don't have any evidence for those other things, despite a lot of searches, then our current "standard model" treats the electron as fundamental.

Historically we have split several "unsplittable" particles.  The modern way to think of this process is to categorize interactions by the energies involved.  Organic molecules can usually be split using energies which correspond to the temperature of a flame.  In a wood fire, that's what the flame *is*: cellulose and oxygen converting to the less-complex carbon dioxide and water, and releasing enough heat that the neighboring cellulose molecules can convert as well.  You can make substantial changes to organic molecules at substantially lower temperatures as well, such as in your cookpan above the flame.

The more famous example is of course the atom, whose name comes from the Greek for "unsplittable," but which can be separated into negative and positive pieces in interactions which energies of a few electron-volts.  An electron-volt (eV) is a unit of energy, like a joule or an erg or a British Thermal Unit, but much smaller. The electron-volt is also the energy scale for a single photon of visible light.

If you separate *all* of the electrons from an atom, then nothing more interesting happens for quite a while.  At energy scales of mega-electron-volts (MeV), a million times more energy than is required to *ionize* an atom, you start to be able to split the atomic *nucleus*.  A dissociated nucleus has positively-charged and electrically-neutral "fundamental" pieces, which have approximately the same mass; we call these protons and neutrons (or "nucleons" when we're not being picky about the charge).

If we keep hitting with more and more energy, then around 100 MeV we start to be able to excite the *nucleons*, making short-lived fragments that are less massive than the nucleons ("mesons"), and other things that act like heavy nucleons ("baryons," although we include the proton and neutron in the list of baryons).  Some of these mesons and heavy baryons are surprisingly long-lived, which was initially referred to as "strangeness," but that became quantitative in short order.  After a couple of decades of study, the spectrum of baryons and mesons was explained in terms of hypothetical quarks and gluons which carry "color charge." The color charge is much like the electric charge, except there are three different ways to be "positive," and the three "positive-colored" states add up to make an object which is color-neutral.  The baryons are made of color-neutral triple of "positive color"; the anti-baryons are made of color-neutral triple of "negative color"; the mesons are colorless because they combine a color with an anticolor.

Note that we can't actually liberate a quark from a hadron, the way that we can liberate an electron from an atom or liberate a nucleon from a nucleus.  The quark model, with its strongly-confined color charges, lays out a set of symmetries which constrain what types of strongly-interacting color-neutral particles we should actually observe, and how the different strongly-interacting particles can decay into each other.  Compare to the periodic table, where the atomic number of each element was deduced (including predicting some "missing elements") long before the discovery of the electron or the nucleus.

The current state-of-the-art for particle collisions is an energy of around ten tera-electron-volts (TeV).  What we have observed in the factor of not-quite-a-million between the meson energy scale and the LHC is *entirely* explainable without *any* compositeness to the quarks or to the electrons.  Everything interesting that high-energy electrons do, like creating photons or particle-antiparticle pairs, appears to be about the properties of the vacuum. We have no evidence for anything special about electrons in the way that color charge is something special about nucleons.

As for shooting with more energy: there is a particular breed of accelerator scientist which will corner you and tell you about why your government should fund their next, even larger, machine.  The desire to search is there.

Comment: I wonder if dried frog pills would work on those accelerator scientists ? :-)

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean, so I’ll [make an assumption](https://abstrusegoose.com/156).

Comment: It's a [Terry Pratchett](https://wiki.lspace.org/Dried_frog_pills) thing.

Answer (score 1):

In theoretical particle physics the electron is considered an elementary particle, therefore the electron cannot be broken down into smaller particles.

Our strongest accelerators or observed interactions from cosmic rays does not suggest it is possible to split an electron.